# Revenue problem from Applovin with Admob mediation

Tags: applovin

I started to use AppLovin SDK and connected to Admob. In the AppLovin performance reporting graph i see estimated revenue $10 from Admob. But when i go to Admob account i see my earning $ 1 only.

How AppLovin system works? Admob or AppLovin paying Admob earnings? I couldn't get answer from support for a week.

Comment: Hey koray, did you find any solution for this?

Comment: Hi, From my experience so far, each network only pays for itself. Although using more than one ad SDK increases the revenue slightly, the errors they cause in the application and unstable operations reduce the visibility of the application in the store. And while trying to make a profit, it can cause more losses. That's why I decided to use only Admob to avoid any more headaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On admob, to see revenues coming from other providers (Applovin, Unity etc) you should look to the Mediation Report. It could take 48h to see all data.

In any case, admob will pay you only the revenues generated by them. In your case, you will receive another payment from applovin, but only at the end of the month and if you generated a minimum threshold of revenues.